# Argument passing when using *args

Tags: python

I have a function defined as such:

```
def foo(arg1, *args):
    print type(args), args
```

Can someone explain the difference between calling the `foo` by passing `expectedResults` in the following 2 ways:

```
expectedResults = ['RESULT1', 'RESULT2']
foo(res, expectedResults)
```

prints the following

```
<type 'tuple'> (['RESULT1', 'RESULT2'],)
```

When passing `expectedResults` with an asterisk like such

```
foo(res, *expectedResults)
```

I get this

```
<type 'tuple'> ('RESULT1', 'RESULT2')
```

My question is: Why does the behavior change between passing `expectedResults` without an asterisk prepended versus with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*expectedResults` unpacks the list before sending the contents.
It's like saying `foo(res, 'RESULT1', 'RESULT2')`, whereas `foo(res, expectedResults)` just passed the list itself as 1 argument, resulting in a tuple with 1 element.

So

```
foo(res, *expectedResults)
```

is equivalent to

```
foo(res, 'RESULT1', 'RESULT2')
```

putting both the strings in the *args parameter, and

```
foo(res, expectedResults)
```

is equivalent to

```
foo(res, ['RESULT1', 'RESULT2'])
```

putting just the list in the *args parameter.

Answer (score 1):

When you have *args the method will automatically create a list out of the arguments, so even if you pass it a list it will just insert the whole list into the tupple (so you have one element in the args, the list expectedResults). When you use the asterix to pass the arguments you instead pass what's in the list.

so foo(res, expectedResults) is the same as passing res, ['RESULT1', 'RESULT2'] (and you can then send multiple lists), while foo(res, *expectedResults) is the same as doing foo(res, 'RESULT1', 'RESULT2').